# The lattice subgroup quotient

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, finite-groups, simplicial-complexes

Let $G$ a finite group and $L(G)$ it's lattice of non trivial subgroups. Is it true that the quotient space $|L(G)|/G$ is contractible, where $|L(G)|$ is the geometric simplicial complex associated to the poset $L(G)$ and where the action of $G$ on the poset $L(G)$ is by conjugation ?

Comment: Assuming that $L(G)$ is the poset of proper non-trivial subgroups of $G$, the answer is no. For example if $G={\mathbb Z}/6$, $|L(G)|/G$ consists of two points.